# Dovecot and two types of password encryption in virtual user's DB field

Tags: encryption, imap, dovecot, courier

I need to migrate from Courier IMAP to Dovecot IMAP.

Can Dovecot IMAP use two types of encrypted passwords on a virtual user's database password field?

I have database with a password field that is encrypted in MySQL format encrypt (MD5) so its limited to 8 chars and SHA-512. Courier is working with that and user can login using old encryption method and SHA-512 encrypted passwords.

Some users have old encryption and some users have new SHA-512 encryption.

Will this work for Dovecot IMAP?

Courier imapd has

```
MYSQL_CRYPT_PWFIELD    password
```

What Dovecot should have?

dovecot-sql.conf

```
default_pass_scheme = SHA512-CRYPT
```

dovecot.conf

```
auth default {
  mechanisms = digest-md5
  passdb sql {
    args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf
  }
```

Will this work the same as it does for Courier?

Answer (score 0):

see e.g. https://doc.dovecot.org/configuration_manual/authentication/password_schemes/

"The password scheme can be overridden for each password by prefixing it with {SCHEME}, for example: {PLAIN}pass."

So, you may just need to provide an appropriate scheme prefix with what you're importing from Courier.

Then see https://wiki.dovecot.org/HowTo/ConvertPasswordSchemes - which shows how you could re-hash an existing password to use a more secure hash.